# What is the canonical way of scaling pictures?

Tags: discussion, support

I often find myself in the situation that I have to resize pictures that are part of my answer or question. My current workflow is that I upload the picture via the usual method and then copy the URL of the uploaded picture into the following html snippet, `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/image.png" height="200">`, which then replaces the automatically created placeholders. That method works well enough, but it involves some extra copying and pasting, so I was wondering if there is a better method out there - possible one that works with the standard picture-uploading-mechanism of this site.

Comment: Someone (maybe even our very own Manish?) used to have userscripts that allowed you to specify size of the upload.  I'm not sure what the status of those scripts is today.

Comment: @jonsca yep, it was me, but I don't know if it works right now and have academics/FOSS stuff to deal with so I can't fix it now (http://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader)

Comment: A compreshensive answer for future visitors is avaiable in a community wiki on formatting: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3048/23561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append `s`,`l`, or `m` to the filename if it's on Imgur:

Normal:

[image]

Medium:

[image: enter link description here]

Small:

[image: enter link description here]

I also wrote [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader) that lets you upload an image, auto-thumbnail it, and link to the original, though I'm not sure if it works anymore since they changed the image upload system. I'll look into this in the summer.

Comment: Thanks, that should work in most cases. If I encounter any problem where this isn't enough, I can still fall back on using my html solution.